# how to get the performance in previous matches of a team

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new to python and pandas, I'm trying to get the performance of the last 5 matches of a team as home and away.
I tried using the code below but the result did not come out as expected. He returned 10 matches and was still wrong.

| index | Date | League | Season | HomeTeam | HomeTeam_id | AwayTeam | AwayTeam_id | HomeErrors | HomeHits | AwayErrors | AwayHits | HomeScore | AwayScore | Winner |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2015-03-06 21:05:00-03:00 | MLB | 2015 | New York Yankees | 25 | Pittsburgh Pirates | 28 | 0.0 | 5.0 | 0.0 | 7.0 | 1.0 | 3.0 | A |
| 1 | 2015-03-07 15:05:00-03:00 | MLB | 2015 | Philadelphia Phillies | 27 | Toronto Blue Jays | 36 | 0.0 | 6.0 | 1.0 | 10.0 | 2.0 | 4.0 | A |
| 2 | 2015-03-07 15:05:00-03:00 | MLB | 2015 | Baltimore Orioles | 4 | Boston Red Sox | 5 | 0.0 | 6.0 | 1.0 | 10.0 | 6.0 | 7.0 | A |
| 3 | 2015-03-07 15:05:00-03:00 | MLB | 2015 | Houston Astros | 15 | New York Yankees | 25 | 0.0 | 12.0 | 0.0 | 12.0 | 4.0 | 9.0 | A |
| 4 | 2015-03-07 15:05:00-03:00 | MLB | 2015 | Miami Marlins | 19 | New York Mets | 24 | 0.0 | 10.0 | 1.0 | 10.0 | 8.0 | 7.0 | H |
| 5 | 2015-03-07 15:05:00-03:00 | MLB | 2015 | Washington Nationals | 37 | St.Louis Cardinals | 33 | 3.0 | 13.0 | 0.0 | 9.0 | 6.0 | 5.0 | H |
| 6 | 2015-03-07 15:05:00-03:00 | MLB | 2015 | Pittsburgh Pirates | 28 | Tampa Bay Rays | 34 | 0.0 | 10.0 | 2.0 | 8.0 | 1.0 | 1.0 | A |
| 7 | 2015-03-07 15:05:00-03:00 | MLB | 2015 | Atlanta Braves | 3 | Detroit Tigers | 12 | 2.0 | 9.0 | 1.0 | 14.0 | 6.0 | 12.0 | A |
| 8 | 2015-03-07 15:05:00-03:00 | MLB | 2015 | Boston Red Sox | 5 | Minnesota Twins | 22 | 1.0 | 16.0 | 1.0 | 4.0 | 4.0 | 2.0 | H |
| 9 | 2015-03-07 15:10:00-03:00 | MLB | 2015 | New York Mets | 24 | Atlanta Braves | 3 | 0.0 | 9.0 | 2.0 | 9.0 | 3.0 | 1.0 | H |

```
df2['Home5WTotal'] = 0
df2['Home5LTotal'] = 0
for team in list(df2['HomeTeam'].unique()):
    for i in range(len(df2[df2['HomeTeam']==team])):
        aux = df2[(df2['HomeTeam']==team) | (df2['AwayTeam']==team)].iloc[i:5+i][['HomeTeam','AwayTeam','Winner']]
        hgames = aux[aux['HomeTeam']==team]['Winner']
        agames = aux[aux['AwayTeam']==team]['Winner']
        if len(aux) < 5:
          break
        else:
          index = aux.index[-1]
          for x in hgames:
              if x == 'H':
                  df2.loc[index, 'Home5WTotal'] += 1
              elif x == 'A':
                  df2.loc[index, 'Home5LTotal'] += 1
          for x in agames:
              if x == 'H':
                  df2.loc[index, 'Home5LTotal'] += 1
              elif x == 'A':
                  df2.loc[index, 'Home5WTotal'] += 1
```

Does anyone know how to fix the problem or have any other solutions?

Comment: We need a minimal example of the dataframe please

Comment: I added the code head

Comment: So do you just want each teams last 5 home and away records

Answer (score 0):

You really need to provide more sample data here. You're wanting us to test code that calculates a teams last 5 games, but only provide a 1 days worth of games for teams.
So I added an additional rows to at least get it going a bit.

Anyways, the way I did it was:

1. sort the dataframe by date so it's in order and get last 5 rows of each teams as home and/or away
2. Groupby by the home or away team
3. to a values_count() to count how many times the out come was home team or away team winning
4. pivot it
5. rename the columns to match/make sense
6. dump each of the home records and away records into a dictionary

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd

last_x_games = 5

cols = ['Date', 'League',   'Season',   'HomeTeam', 'HomeTeam_id',  'AwayTeam'  ,'AwayTeam_id', 'HomeErrors',   'HomeHits', 'AwayErrors',   'AwayHits'  ,'HomeScore','AwayScore'    ,'Winner']
data = [
['2015-03-06 21:05:00-03:00',   'MLB',  '2015', 'New York Yankees', '25'    ,'Pittsburgh Pirates'   ,'28',  '0.0',  '5.0',  '0.0',  '7.0',  '1.0',  '3.0',  'A'],
['2015-03-07 15:05:00-03:00',   'MLB',  '2015', 'Philadelphia Phillies',    '27',   'Toronto Blue Jays',    '36',   '0.0'   ,'6.0', '1.0'   ,'10.0',    '2.0',  '4.0',  'A'],
['2015-03-07 15:05:00-03:00',   'MLB',  '2015', 'Baltimore Orioles',    '4',    'Boston Red Sox',   '5'  ,            '0.0',    '6.0',  '1.0'   ,'10.0',    '6.0',  '7.0'   ,'A'],
['2015-03-07 15:05:00-03:00',   'MLB',  '2015', 'Houston Astros',   '15',   'New York Yankees'  ,'25',  '0.0',  '12.0', '0.0',  '12.0', '4.0',  '9.0',  'A'],
['2015-03-07 15:05:00-03:00',   'MLB',  '2015', 'Miami Marlins' ,'19'   ,'New York Mets'    ,'24',  '0.0',  '10.0'  '1.0',  '10.0', '8.0',  '7.0',  'H'],
['2015-03-07 15:05:00-03:00',   'MLB',  '2015', 'Washington Nationals', '37',   'St.Louis Cardinals',   '33',   '3.0',  '13.0'  ,'0.0'  ,'9.0', '6.0',  '5.0',  'H'],
['2015-03-07 15:05:00-03:00',   'MLB',  '2015', 'Pittsburgh Pirates',   '28',   'Tampa Bay Rays',   '34',   '0.0',  '10.0'  ,'2.0', '8.0',  '1.0',  '1.0',  'A'],
['2015-03-07 15:05:00-03:00',   'MLB',  '2015', 'Atlanta Braves',   '3',    'Detroit Tigers'    ,'12',  '2.0'   ,'9.0', '1.0'   ,'14.0',    '6.0',  '12.0'  ,'A'],
['2015-03-07 15:05:00-03:00',   'MLB',  '2015', 'Boston Red Sox',   '5' ,'Minnesota Twins'  ,'22'   ,'1.0'  ,'16.0',    '1.0',  '4.0'   ,'4.0', '2.0',  'H'],
['2015-03-07 15:10:00-03:00',   'MLB',  '2015', 'New York Mets' ,'24',  'Atlanta Braves'    ,'3',   '0.0'   ,'9.0'  ,'2.0', '9.0'   ,'3.0', '1.0'   ,'H'],
['2015-03-07 21:05:00-03:00',   'MLB',  '2015', 'New York Yankees', '25'    ,'Pittsburgh Pirates'   ,'28',  '0.0',  '5.0',  '0.0',  '7.0',  '1.0',  '3.0',  'H'],
['2015-03-08 15:05:00-03:00',   'MLB',  '2015', 'Philadelphia Phillies',    '27',   'Toronto Blue Jays',    '36',   '0.0'   ,'6.0', '1.0'   ,'10.0',    '2.0',  '4.0',  'A'],
['2015-03-08 15:05:00-03:00',   'MLB',  '2015', 'Baltimore Orioles',    '4',    'Boston Red Sox',   '5'  ,            '0.0',    '6.0',  '1.0'   ,'10.0',    '6.0',  '7.0'   ,'A'],
['2015-03-08 15:05:00-03:00',   'MLB',  '2015', 'Houston Astros',   '15',   'New York Yankees'  ,'25',  '0.0',  '12.0', '0.0',  '12.0', '4.0',  '9.0',  'A'],
['2015-03-08 15:05:00-03:00',   'MLB',  '2015', 'Miami Marlins' ,'19'   ,'New York Mets'    ,'24',  '0.0',  '10.0'  '1.0',  '10.0', '8.0',  '7.0',  'H'],
['2015-03-08 15:05:00-03:00',   'MLB',  '2015', 'Washington Nationals', '37',   'St.Louis Cardinals',   '33',   '3.0',  '13.0'  ,'0.0'  ,'9.0', '6.0',  '5.0',  'A'],
['2015-03-08 15:05:00-03:00',   'MLB',  '2015', 'Pittsburgh Pirates',   '28',   'Tampa Bay Rays',   '34',   '0.0',  '10.0'  ,'2.0', '8.0',  '1.0',  '1.0',  'H'],
['2015-03-08 15:05:00-03:00',   'MLB',  '2015', 'Atlanta Braves',   '3',    'Detroit Tigers'    ,'12',  '2.0'   ,'9.0', '1.0'   ,'14.0',    '6.0',  '12.0'  ,'A'],
['2015-03-08 15:05:00-03:00',   'MLB',  '2015', 'Boston Red Sox',   '5' ,'Minnesota Twins'  ,'22'   ,'1.0'  ,'16.0',    '1.0',  '4.0'   ,'4.0', '2.0',  'H'],
['2015-03-08 15:10:00-03:00',   'MLB',  '2015', 'New York Mets' ,'24',  'Atlanta Braves'    ,'3',   '0.0'   ,'9.0'  ,'2.0', '9.0'   ,'3.0', '1.0'   ,'A']]


df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=cols)
df = df.sort_values('Date').reset_index(drop=True)

dfs_dict = {}
for each, abbr in {'Home':['H', 'A'], 'Away': ['A', 'H']}.items():
    col = f'{each}Team'
    
    grouped = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(col).tail(last_x_games).groupby(col)['Winner'].value_counts())
    grouped.columns = ['count']
    grouped = grouped.reset_index(drop=False)
    grouped.columns = [col,'Winner','count']

    dfRecord = grouped.pivot(index = col,
                  columns = 'Winner',
                  values = 'count').fillna(0)
    dfRecord = dfRecord.rename(columns={abbr[0]:'W',
                                   abbr[1]:'L'})
```

**Output:**

```
for each, table in dfs_dict.items():
    print(f'\n{each} Records for Last {last_x_games} Games:')
    print(table, '\n')
        dfRecord = dfRecord[['W','L']]
        
        dfs_dict[each] = dfRecord


Home Records for Last 5 Games:
Winner                   W    L
HomeTeam                       
Atlanta Braves         0.0  2.0
Baltimore Orioles      0.0  2.0
Boston Red Sox         2.0  0.0
Houston Astros         0.0  2.0
New York Mets          1.0  1.0
New York Yankees       1.0  1.0
Philadelphia Phillies  0.0  2.0
Pittsburgh Pirates     1.0  1.0
Washington Nationals   1.0  1.0 


Away Records for Last 5 Games:
Winner                W    L
AwayTeam                    
Atlanta Braves      1.0  1.0
Boston Red Sox      2.0  0.0
Detroit Tigers      2.0  0.0
Minnesota Twins     0.0  2.0
New York Yankees    2.0  0.0
Pittsburgh Pirates  1.0  1.0
St.Louis Cardinals  1.0  1.0
Tampa Bay Rays      1.0  1.0
Toronto Blue Jays   2.0  0.0
```